# QGIS Qtiles from EPSG 3395

Tags: qgis, tiles, mercator

I am having issues while converting my layer from 4326 to 3395. My Qtiles does not make tiles.

I have a source mapinfo in 4326 with long, lat pairs. My goal is to show this on a maps.yandex (3395 mercator) as a tiles layer. I can make tiles only from 4326.